# iWork ‘06 apps won't start due to missing files after restore

Tags: macos, iwork

Recently I restored my PowerBook G4 with macOS Tiger. I copied the all apps and QuickTime Pro license too. But when I open Pages, Number or Keynote a message that tell me that some files are missing appear. I cannot report here the message because my PowerBook is in Italian so I don’t now the translation in other languages.

i copied the apps from previsius system Folder, when i restored it i chosed to move the old system in this folder.

Comment: "copied the apps" - where from? It's too long ago to remember, but it wouldn't surprise me if it used a full installer rather than drag & drop, which means you will have components missing. If you could add the error messages in Italian, I'm sure someone can figure out a translation.

Comment: Have you tried installing from the original disc?

Comment: Please post the text of the Italian message. It may still be useful, and qualcuno potrebbe parlare italiano, magari.

Comment: Ok, capito (Italian, not important)

Comment: i don't have the discs